# how do i know if a tcxlookupcombobox editor has been changed in delphi?

Tags: devexpress

I have a tcxlookupcombobox editor on a form and I want to know that it hasn't changed so I can show a message like "no changes selected".
I'm lost because I'm a beginner.
I'm also new here so be patient.
Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tcxLookupComboBox.Properties.OnChange` event to set a boolean flag to indicate that changes happened.

If you want to be really fancy and you don't want to detect changes A -> B -> A, you'll have to remember the initial value in the `Properties.OnpPupup` handler, then compare with that value afterwards.